# React - Any way to cancel (or ignore) async action on 'OnChange' handler?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous

I have a code here https://codesandbox.io/embed/cranky-glade-82leu

In here, I have a 'verifyUserNameAvailable' function under 'api/' folder.  In this function, I added 10sec delay to test extreme case when our API server is bad.

When user enters a valid email address (valid email format like abc@test.net), I see it's email address in helperText line 10 sec later. (This is because I added 10 sec delay in 'verifyUserNameAvailable'.)

When user enters 'abc@test.net', 'abc2@test.net' and 'abc3@test.net' 3 emails one by one without waiting for 10 seconds, I see that all three emails are displayed in sequential order on helperText line. (I guess this is expected given what I have in the code now.)

My question here-> I want the helperText line to show the most latest one only.   When user enters above 3 email addresses and 'abc3@test.net' is the last one on the textField, I want to just show the 'abc3@test.net' on helperText line not the others.

Is there anyway to check what's actually on textfield and discard or abort all irrelevant async requests?

Comment: Any particular reason your `errors` is an array? Do you expect to be able to show multiple errors for this field at the same time?

Comment: I don't have any specific reason for using an array.  I am still learning. :)

Comment: Do you want to provide the user the ability to test multiple emails (make multiple async calls) before the first is confirmed? Generally I would disable the handler while a request is processing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a way to do this without cancelling the `verifyUserNameAvailable` promise: Keep track of the number of requests in flight, and ignore any responses other than the latest one.

Here's what that could look like in your example, this uses `useRef` to keep track of the latest request value (see the React docs for `useRef` to see how this works https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref):

```
export const EmailTextField = props => {
  const { onStateChange } = props;
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    errors: [],
    onChange: false,
    pristine: true,
    touched: false,
    value: null
  });

  // `useRef` holds a mutable value that lasts as long
  // as the component, staying "more up to date" than the
  // current closure.
  const requestsInFlight = useRef(0);

  const helperText = "Email address will be used as your username.";

  const handleBlur = async event => {
    // Email Validation logic
    const emailAddress = event.target.value;
    const matches = event.target.value.match(
      `[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+.[a-z]{2,3}`
    );
    if (matches) {
      // If there's a match, increment the ref for in-flight requests
      requestsInFlight.current += 1;

      await verifyUserNameAvailable(emailAddress);

      // After the response comes back, decrement the ref, and if
      // there are any requests still in flight, ignore that response.
      requestsInFlight.current -= 1;
      if (requestsInFlight.current > 0) {
        return;
      }
      const updatedState = {
        ...state,
        touched: true,
        value: emailAddress,
        errors: [emailAddress]
      };
      setState(updatedState);
      onStateChange(updatedState);
    } else {
      ...
    }
  };
```

Comment: wow I didn't even think of using useRef.  Thank you very much for suggestion.

Comment: Glad it helped! I thought of a way to simplify it a bit and updated the code example.

Comment: Say we make a request `A` and then a request `B`. If `B` comes back first, would we ignore it because `A` is still in flight? If so, how would we implement it so that we only care about the result of the last request made - i.e. `B`

Comment: To answer myself, track the latest promise called using `const lastPromise=useRef()`. Then to update that ref: `verifyPromise = verifyUserNameAvailable(emailAddress); lastPromise.current=verifyPromise; const response = await verifyPromise();`. Then we check if  `lastPromise.current === verifyPromise` before using its response.

Answer (score 0):

Lets think about possible solutions from deepest level.

1. Internally you calling `setTimeout`. Timeout can be cancelled with [`clearTimeout`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp). I don't think that this is the way you're looking for, so I will not describe how to implement this.
2. `setTimeout` is wrapped with `Promise`. Unfortunately, Promises are not cancelable in current version of JS. There is [proposal](https://github.com/bergus/promise-cancellation) for it.
3. I suspect, that you'll use code with some API to fetch data from backend. If you'll use axios, it provides cancellation of pending requests to backend using [cancellation token](https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation) (and cancellation is based on cancellation proposal for JS).
4. And if you'll use Redux in your app, you may consider Redux-saga for backend requests. It also [supports cancellation](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/TaskCancellation.html).